# CSS Hover not called with margin-top minus value

Tags: html, css

I want the paging for my carousel to overlap the carousel and the div underneath it. However, by setting the paging's container to `margin-top: -49px;`, hover is not being recognised by css on the bottom half of the pager.

After more debugging, I discovered if I add:

```
.under-div:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

then hovering over the bottom half of my paging control triggers the blue background in `.under-div`

I added `.slick-dots:hover{ background-color: red; }` for demo purposes here:

[image]    [image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slick-list draggable">
    <-- here is the carousel -->
</div>

<div class="slick-controls">
    <ul class="slick-dots" style="display: table;bottom: -49px;">
        <li class="slick-active">
            <button type="button" data-role="none">1</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" data-role="none">2</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slick-controls .slick-dots {
    display: table! important;
    width: auto;
    line-height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -25px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    margin: auto;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.slick-controls {
    margin-top: -49px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding position:relative; z-index: 2; to .slick-controls? if you could provide a jsfiddle, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that your hover is being captured by the carousel, which is being rendered on top of the rest, and there's no reason CSS should allow what's below to capture it as well, as what's below is not a parent of the carousel.

when you have a structure that looks like this:

```
<a></a>
<b></b>
```

where `a` overlaps `b`, only one of them will receive the hover. If `b` is `relative` and `a` is `absolute`, then `a` will be capturing the hover, for example.

this is different when your structure looks like this:

```
<a>
 <c></c>
</a>
<b></b>
```

assuming `c` overlaps with `a`, when you hover on `c`, both `c` and `a` will capture the event. `b` acts in the same way as it did in the previous example.

There is no good way to overcome this, unless you want JS to be involved, in which case you'd be capturing every event and calculating which elements you want to send it to, then adding a class like `.hover` to them, but this is highly discouraged.

Chances are, you're doing something wrong if your carousel displays on top of some part of the page that you should be able to interact with.